# using cache=True in numba 0.56.4 causing crash on second running

Tags: python, caching, numba

Here is a simple python program to sort an array of numbers using the numba JIT compiler   0.56.4:

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit(cache=True)
def heapify(arr: np.array, n: int, i: int):
    largest = i  # Initialize largest as root
    l = 2 * i + 1  # left = 2*i + 1
    r = 2 * i + 2  # right = 2*i + 2
    if l < n and arr[i] < arr[l]:
        largest = l
    if r < n and arr[largest] < arr[r]:
        largest = r
    if largest != i:
        (arr[i], arr[largest]) = (arr[largest], arr[i])  # swap
        heapify(arr, n, largest)

@njit(cache=True)
def heapSort(arr: np.array) -> np.array:
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n // 2 - 1, -1, -1):
        heapify(arr, n, i)
    for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
        (arr[i], arr[0]) = (arr[0], arr[i])  # swap
        heapify(arr, i, 0)
    return arr

data = np.random.random(5)
print(data)
o = heapSort(data)
print(o)
```

With the cache=True flag in the decorator, the program runs the first time, but on the second running I get the following error:

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

When I remove the cache=True flag, the code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to go away if I explicitly declare the function signatures in the @njit decorators:

```
...
@njit(void(float64[:], int64, int64), cache=True)
def heapify(arr: np.array, n: int, i: int):

...

@njit(float64[:](float64[:]), cache=True)
def heapSort(arr: np.array) -> np.array:
...
```

Doing this seems to have the added benefit of making the compilation process much faster, rendering the caching unnecessary in most cases.  Of course you wouldn't notice the difference anyway in this toy example, but I have numba-compiled code that takes 27s to run the first time and about 4s the second time if I don't include the signatures. When I added the signatures, running for the first time took about 5s so compilation time has been reduced from about 23s to about 1s.  I guess the JIT compiler uses a lot of time trying to infer the data types if you don't explicitly state them.